# Does anyone know why i am getting this basic error when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

I used multiprocessing to launch 2 fonction at the sime time because i need them to work in parallel, but i am getting a common basic error and i don't know why. i tried to do so debugging python is telling me server is defined before using it so am i having this issues ?

```py
def add_users():
    global users
    global client
    global client_addr
    users = []
    while True:
        print('2')
        server.listen(100)
        client, client_addr = server.accept()
        print(colored(f'[+] {client_addr} Client connected to the server', 'yellow'))
        users.append([client, client_addr])

def exec(c, cA):
    # others code

#@ray.remote
def mid():
    a = input(colored("#-> ", 'green'))

    if a == 'ls':
        if len(users) != 0:
            print(colored(users, 'yellow'))
            mid()
        else:
            print(colored("No user connected.", 'yellow'))
            mid()
    elif a.split(' ')[0] == 'connect':
        for t in len(users):
            if users[t][1] == a.split(' ')[1]:
                exec(users[t][0], users[t][1])

#ray.get([mid.remote(), add_users.remote()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    colorama.init()
    #ray.init()
    os.system('color')

    print(colored(' ______     __  __        __    __     ______     __  __     ______     _____    ', 'red'))
    time.sleep(1)
    print(colored('/\  == \   /\ \_\ \      /\ "-./  \   /\  __ \   /\ \/\ \   /\  __ \   /\  __-.  ', 'red'))
    time.sleep(1)
    print(colored('\ \  __<   \ \____ \     \ \ \-./\ \  \ \ \/\ \  \ \ \_\ \  \ \  __ \  \ \ \/\ \ ', 'red'))
    time.sleep(1)
    print(colored(' \ \_____\  \/\_____\     \ \_\ \ \_\  \ \_____\  \ \_____\  \ \_\ \_\  \ \____- ', 'red'))
    time.sleep(1)
    print(colored('  \/_____/   \/_____/      \/_/  \/_/   \/_____/   \/_____/   \/_/\/_/   \/____/ \n', 'red'))

    HOST = '0.0.0.0'
    PORT = 8081
    global server
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print(server)
    print(colored('[+] Server Started', 'magenta'))
    print(colored('[+] Listening For Client Connection ...', 'magenta'))

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=mid)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=add_users)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

The error : `server.listen(100)` `NameError: name 'server' is not defined`

Comment: `server` is not defined in the process you are executing `add_users` in (it is only defined in the main process in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.  Indeed, you cannot just use a global socket and multiprocessing. You have to understand, you are *creating two seperate python processes*

Comment: @MattDMo that's not going to work with a `socket.socket` object in multiprocessing

Comment: yeah this is the thing, i have tried to use threading instead but it's like normal execution. My goal is to execute the both fonction at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Globals are not shared between multiple processes.
You need to pass variables (i.e. `server`) as arguments to process `p2`.

So you can define `add_users` to have `server` argument, as so:

```
def add_users(server):
    global users
    global client
    global client_addr
    users = []
    while True:
        print('2')
        server.listen(100)
        client, client_addr = server.accept()
        print(colored(f'[+] {client_addr} Client connected to the server', 'yellow'))
        users.append([client, client_addr])
```

and use the process `args` to pass the `server` to the `add_user`:
`p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=add_users, args=(server,))`

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes maybe it will help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).